How to run segment filters in google api v4 BetaAnalyticsDataClient
im trying to get purchase eventCount , where the purchase event is followed by a tryon event any time in the past. in the api dashboard in can get the data , but im unable to get the same in the backed. im using node and "@google-analytics/data" package.
const { BetaAnalyticsDataClient } = require("@google-analytics/data");

const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

propertyId = "id";

app.use("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { startDay } = req.query;
  try {
    const [resp] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [
        {
          startDate: startDay,
          endDate: "yesterday",
        },
      ],
      dimensions: [
        {
          name: "eventName", // Added dimension for event name
        },
        {
          name: "customEvent:SKUS",
        },
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          name: "eventCount",
        },
      ],

      dimensionFilter: {
        orGroup: {
          expressions: [
            {
              filter: {
                fieldName: "eventName",
                stringFilter: {
                  value: "Number Of Trials",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              filter: {
                fieldName: "eventName",
                stringFilter: {
                  value: "purchased",
                },
              },
              // operator: "FOLLOWED_BY", // Indicates "followed by" condition
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    res.send({ resp });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error, port: process.env.PORT });
  }
});


i tried setting segment option in the request but after looking at he documentation , i found out that there is no option to set segementFilter in the request body.
